# on google sheets, use "this line" instead of line number

Tags: google-sheets

[image: Google sheet showing the problem]

I have the following formula on a google sheet:
`IFERROR(Vlookup(A3,INDIRECT(A$1),1,false),0)`

My desire is to have this formula use A3 on line 3, A4 on line 4 and so on

However, sometimes I get it wrong. I copy and paste it, and I wind up using A3 on line 4

What I want is, instead of writing A4 in the formula for line 4, write "column A of this line". Is there an appropriate command for that?

Answer (score 0):

`IFERROR(Vlookup(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()),INDIRECT(A$1),1,false),0)`

this seems to do the trick :)

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length.  It would be helpful to future visitors if you explained why your solution works.